# SQL Server calculating working hours with multiple IN OUT

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, dynamic-queries

I have a table with employees attendance logs from sensor machines, employees can have multiple IN & OUT entries in a single day, I want to calculate the number of hours an employess remained IN (total worked hours) by ignoring the Time OUT
I've been looking for this solution for two days, but can't get the required result.

## Logs Table is as under (checkin_out_log)

```
╔════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ emp_id ║ shift ║       check_time        ║ check_type ║
╠════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║      2 ║     1 ║ 2018-02-22 07:00:44.000 ║ C-IN       ║
║      2 ║     1 ║ 2018-02-22 13:00:35.000 ║ B-OUT      ║
║      2 ║     1 ║ 2018-02-22 13:30:46.000 ║ B-IN       ║
║      2 ║     5 ║ 2018-02-22 16:00:55.000 ║ C-OUT      ║
╚════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

### Desired OUTPUT is :

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ emp_id ║  IN Hrs  ║       Date              ║ OUT HRS    ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║      2 ║ 08:30    ║ 2018-01-22              ║ 00:30      ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

[Here is the data in query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzfbx.jpg)

[Here is what I get in results with data shown in screenshot with your query, please guide whats wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahfrF.jpg)

Comment: If B-OUT is missing, what'll be your desired output?

Comment: then I need to just show Improper, no calculation in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the IN and OUT are always in pair.

You can make use of LEAD() window function to get next check_time. And use CASE WHEN condition to determine it is IN or OUT time

```
select  emp_id, 
        in_hrs = sum(in_mins) / 60.0, 
        check_date = convert(date, check_time), 
        out_hrs = sum(out_mins) / 60.0
from
(
    select  *, 
            in_mins = CASE  WHEN    check_type in ('C-IN', 'B-IN')
                            AND     LEAD(check_type) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY check_time) in ('C-OUT', 'B-OUT')
                            THEN    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                                             check_time, 
                                             LEAD(check_time) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY check_time))
                            ELSE    0
                            END,
            out_mins= CASE  WHEN    check_type in ('C-OUT', 'B-OUT')
                            AND     LEAD(check_type) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY check_time) in ('B-IN')
                            THEN    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                                             check_time, 
                                             LEAD(check_time) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY check_time))
                            ELSE    0
                            END
    from    checkin_out_log
) d
group by emp_id, convert(date, check_time)
```

Edit : added condition to validate cases where IN without OUT or vice-versa. The in/out will be ignore and no calculation.

The added condition are

```
LEAD(check_type) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY check_time) in ('C-OUT', 'B-OUT')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i had the same thoughts, but in my case there can be a missing OUT entry in the same date, so its not getting the desired output, can you please modify it or suggest to tackle this scenario

Comment: first you need to specify how do you want to handle if there is a missing OUT or IN entry.

Comment: then I need to just show Improper, no calculation in that case

Comment: Please check the images attached in my edited question, the query not returning expected results, thanks

Comment: I've sorted the reason , only thing to change was to remove 'C-IN' from the out_hrs LEAD clause, becuase we don't need to look for subsquent 'C-IN' if someone has checked out (C-OUT), rest of your query is fine, you saved my "weeks"  :) thumbsup